# Editing private class member from a member function for another class

Tags: c++, class

My two classes are:

```
class sequence
{
public:
...

private:
int number_of_samples;
float* samples;
};

class FIR
{
public:
...

sequence* apply_filter(const sequence& f);

private:
int number_of_coefficients;
float* coefficients;
};
```

When I run the following member function:

```
sequence* FIR::apply_filter(const sequence& f)
{
ofstream output_sequence_file("output.txt");
output_sequence_file<<number_of_coefficients<<endl;
sequence* Vout = new sequence;
for(int i=0;i<number_of_coefficients;i++)
{
    if (0==i) Vout->samples[i]=coefficients[i]*f.samples[i];
    else Vout->samples[i]=coefficients[i] * f.samples[i] + Vout->samples[i-1];

output_sequence_file<<Vout->samples[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

I get an error saying: 'samples' is a private member of sequence.

Any help? 
Thank you

Comment: You can't access `private` members of another class, unless you provide a `friend` relationship, or provide some public getter/setter functions.

Answer (score 0):

Move `samples` into the public section of `class sequence` or declare `FIR::apply_filter()` a `friend` of `class sequence`. Private members of a class cannot be accessed by other classes or functions unless they have been granted the privilege.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but the Dr. said samples must be private (I'm doing software engineering design basics) also he said, "you are expected to use friend in this module for stream operators only"!

Comment: @SultanBawazeer So you still have the `friend` option, or did the Dr. deny using that also?

Comment: See the `friend` part of my answer.